# Mapping object of keys to array of values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object  of keys like this :

```
var x = {a,b}
```

And I have an array of values like this :

```
var y = [1,2]
```

How can I map keys to object like this in the most optimized way and without using two arrays:

```
{ a: 1, b: 2 }
```

Comment: what have you done to guarantee the enumeration order of the keys?

Comment: See `Object.keys()` and `Object.fromEntries()`.

Comment: `{a, b}` is equivalent to `{a: a, b: b}` but `a` and `b` are not defined.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Object.keys()` to iterate over the keys of `x`. Then use `map()` to combine these with the corresponding elements of `y`. Finally, use `Object.fromEntries()` to convert this array into a new object.

```js
var x = {a:null,b:null};
var y = [1, 2];
result = Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(x).map((key, i) => [key, y[i]]));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need three parts:

1. Take the keys array and values array as new array.
2. Transpose this array to get an array with key/value pairs.
3. Create an object from the pairs with [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

```js
const
    transpose = array => array.reduce((r, a) => a.map((v, i) => [...(r[i] || []), v]), []),
    x = ['a', 'b'],
    y = [1, 2],
    result = Object.fromEntries(transpose([x, y]));

console.log(result);
```